# Where do Kafka consumers get the first version of Avro schema from?

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, quarkus

Most Quarkus examples that illustrate the use of Avro and Service registry combine consumer and producer in the same project. In doing so, the schema and the generated classes are available to the producer and the consumer.

I understand that the role of the schema registry is to maintain various versions of a schema and make them available to consumers.

What I do not fully understand is how and when the consumer pulls the schema from the registry. For instance, how does the consumer's team get the initial version of the schema? Do they just go to the registry and download it manually? Do they use the maven plugin to download it and generate the sources?

In the case of Quarkus, the avro extension automatically generates the Java source from avro schema. I wonder if it also downloads the initial schema for consumers.

Answer (score 0):

The consumers can optionally download the schema from the registry. Then the consumer should be configured to use a SpecificRecord deserialization.

For the Confluent serialization format, the Schema ID is embedded in each record. When the consumer deserializer processes the bytes, it'll always perform a lookup from the registry for that ID.

Avro requires both a writer schema (the one that's downloaded from that ID), and a reader schema (either the one that the consumer app developer has downloaded, or defaults to the writer schema), and then schema evolution is evaluated.

Quarkus/Kafka doesn't really matter, here. It's entirely done within the Avro library after HTTP calls to the Registry.